# navigating from asp.net application to an other Twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

when i am navigating  to Twitter  from my asp.net application  using href html element    i am getting "Webpage Error Do you want to debug " message

can any suggest the solution please
let me know any comment if anyone can't understand.

thanks in advance.

Comment: it would help to see your href attribute to understand why it's doing it, might be a javascript issue or something

Answer (score 0):

Does your href attribute have "`http://`" prefix? without it, sometimes links are calculated related to the current asp.net application.

Comment: then please post the snippet from your application which shows the content you have.